# Connecting to IOT remotely like the Home camera/alarm system

Tags: networking, iot

I see a lot of Cameras for home monitoring and they are accessible from an app remotely.
How do these applications manage to do that without a static IP address? I am thinking of doing something similar for my own IOT network.

Any useful material or information regarding real-world implementation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

These devices get around this issue by connecting to a 3rd party.  In your home, The software or IoT device connects to a 3rd party.  This 3rd party is usually the manufacturer's website/network.  Then are sending out a heartbeat to the remote network with their connection information.  From there 1 of 2 things happens.  The manufacturer acts as a middleman sending data between your phone and home network.  Or to access this data from your phone, the app connects to the 3rd party network and it passes the data to your IoT/software, which then initiates the connection to your phone.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have more confidence in my project now. Do you know what sorts of connectivity technology they use to achieve this? I mean the manufacturers since I will also be acting like one for my own network.